# What's a good way to handle "async" commits?

Tags: oracle, transactions, transactionscope, odp.net, msdtc

I have a WCF service that uses [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html) to read data from an Oracle database. The service also writes to the database, but indirectly, as all updates and inserts are achieved through an older layer of business logic that I access via COM+, which I wrap in a [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx). The older layer connects to Oracle via ODBC, not ODP.NET.

The problem I have is that because Oracle uses a two-phase-commit, and because the older business layer is using ODBC and not ODP.NET, the transaction *sometimes* returns on the `TransactionScope.Commit()` before the data is actually available for reads from the service layer.

I see [a similar post about a Java user having trouble like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983296/oracle-lag-between-commit-and-select) as well on Stack Overflow.

A representative from Oracle [posted that there isn't much I can do about this](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=958260&tstart=0) problem:

> This maybe due to the way OLETx
>   ITransaction::Commit() method behaves.
>   After phase 1 of the 2PC (i.e. the
>   prepare phase) if all is successful,
>   **commit can return even if the resource
>   managers haven't actually committed**.
>   After all the successful "prepare" is
>   a guarantee that the resource managers
>   cannot arbitrarily abort after this
>   point. Thus even though a resource
>   manager couldn't commit because it
>   didn't receive a "commit" notification
>   from the MSDTC (due to say a
>   communication failure), the
>   component's commit request returns
>   successfully. If you select rows from
>   the table(s) immediately you may
>   sometimes see the actual commit occur
>   in the database after you have already
>   executed your select. Your select will
>   not therefore see the new rows due to
>   consistent read semantics. There is
>   nothing we can do about this in Oracle
>   as the "commit success after
>   successful phase 1" optimization is
>   part of the MSDTC's implementation.

***So, my question is this:***

How should I go about dealing with the possible delay ("asyc" via the title) problem of figuring out when the second part of the 2PC actually occurs, so I can be sure that data I inserted (indirectly) is actually available to be selected after the `Commit()` call returns?

**How do big systems deal with the fact that the data might not be ready for reading immediately?**

Comment: Have you tried what is suggested in that link? Moving to odp.net 11.1.07.20 and Oracle 11.

Comment: I wish I could just upgrade, but the Oracle version is out of my control. The business layer is not yet ready for 11 and won't be anytime soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the whole transaction has prepared and a commit outcome decided by the TransactionManager, therefore eventually (barring heuristic damage) the Resource Managers will receive their commit message and complete. However, there are no guarantees as to how long that might take - could be days, no timeouts apply, having voted "commit" in the Prepare the Resource Manager **must** wait to hear the collective outcome.

Under these conditions, the simplest approach is to take "an understood, we're thinking" approach. Your request has been understood, but you actually don't know the outcome, and that's what you tell the user. Yes, in all sane circumstances the request will complete, but under some conditions operators could actually choose to intervene in the transaction manually (and maybe cause heuristic damage in doing so.)

To go one step further, you could start a new transaction and perform some queries to see if the data is there. Now, if you are populating a result screen you will naturally be doing such as query. The question would be what to do if the expected results are not there. So again, tell the user "your recent request is being processed, hit refresh to see if it's complete". Or retry automatically (I don't much like auto retry - prefer to educate the user that it's effectively an asynch operation.)

Comment: Yeah. Generally, 3 seconds sleep is more than enough, but far slower than the Commit() actually takes (few hundred ms response, practically). Perhaps I should look to make the WCF service reply callback be async as well, and sleep until the data is ready.

Comment: Is it possible to see that the data is there? You could insert an increasing number via COM+ and query this number via ODP.NET.

Comment: Tuinstoel... that is exactly my next brainstorm! I could add some kind of "marker" in my transaction - a separate INSERT that only I know about, that goes right before the commit. When I am able to read it, then I know the data from the overall transaction is available to be read?

Comment: Give it a try and let us know.