# Oracle just inserted data not found

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a table `t`:

```sql
table t (c number);
```

I am trying to select a value from this table and if the value is not found, insert it and then select it again. But sometimes even after just inserting the record, I don't find the row.

Here is a simplified toy version of the code (ignore the injectable SQLs):

```java
for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
    int n = x * 10000;
    new Thread(() -> {
        try (Connection c = Connections.get();
             Connection c2 = Connections.get()) {
            for (int i = n; i < n + 10000; i++) {
                int retries = 0;
                while (true) {
                    String sql = "select * from t where c = " + i;
                    try (PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
                         ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {

                        if (rs.next()) {
                            System.out.println("found " + i);
                            break;
                        } else {
                            retries++;
                            if (retries > 1) {
                                System.out.println("It happened. Not found " + i + " (retries: " + retries + ")");
                                System.exit(1);
                            }
                            System.out.println("Not found " + i + " (retries: " + retries + ")");
                            sql = "insert into t values (" + i + ")";
                            try (PreparedStatement ps2 = c2.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                                ps2.executeUpdate();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }).start();
}
```

It occasionally prints the below and stops. Sometimes very quickly and sometime after a few minutes.

```
It happened. Not found <whatever> (retries: 2)
```

After this error, If I try to run `select * from t where c = <whatever>`, I find the record.

In theory, this shouldn't happen. 
It happens only in multi instance database with multiple load-balanced addresses.
It doesn't happen in regular single instance database.

BTW, no one else is using this table except me.

The DBA just says that "everything is a'right" on their side.

Does anyone know of similar issue and how to fix this?

Comment: have you tried using one connection instead of two? I could imagine that each gets connected to a distinct instance and there is a delay before the instances get synchronized (eventually also because the connections (DB sessions) are not being closed)

Comment: Try to debug the result of `ps2.executeUpdate();`, maybe insert operation failed for some reason.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I cannot use the same connection. Because the first connection would be running a different transaction which may be rollbacked independently of the second one. Also, commit should be enough to persist. I shouldn't need to close the connection. It may not be actually closed anyway even if I did close it. I am using connection pool.

Comment: @meng - If it failed, I should get an SQLException, no?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Uncertain, as the api said, SQLException throws when `if a database access error occurs; this method is called on a closed PreparedStatement or the SQL statement returns a ResultSet object`.

Comment: there is no commit in posted code, is it? and, exactly, "may be rollbacked" - that would only make sense if data is not yet committed and a second transaction will not see changes from an uncommitted transaction (DB cannot know if it will be committed or rolled back in future)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger As I mentioned, this is simplified version of the code. There is a transaction running with connection `c` and we run a `select` on it. If we don't get the row, we get a new connection `c2`, `insert` the record with this. `commit` the `c2`. then try to select the row with connection `c` again. Now the connection `c` should be able to see the data we just committed with `c2` right?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Also, in this simplified version, I still get the same issue even though `c` is not actually running a transaction

Comment: Are you connecting to a RAC maybe?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think it's RAC yes. Does that matter?

Comment: simplified code or not, I can only *know* what is posted, everything else is just guessing (like commit's and auto-commit being enabled, ....)

Comment: Yes, that matters. The second connection might wind up on the other RAC node, and the time between the insert and the select might not be enough to allow Oracle to replicate the data between the two nodes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Oh.. My intuition was that RAC should behave the same way as regular database (with added scaling) from application perspective. Do you know a way to fix (workaround?) it please?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Wait.. Is Oracle Exadata RAC? we use Exadata. The issue occurs only with Exadata machine and not on local development single instance db.

Comment: Yes, Exadata is RAC

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Do you know a way to workaround this please? What we have is a sleep of 1 sec when we encounter this issue. That is causing a lot of sleeping.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983296/oracle-lag-between-commit-and-select) seems related